# How can I authenticate SharePoint user credentials

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to access a sharepoint application from my desktop application (written in C#). How should I pass credentials and verify authentication?

Comment: What do you mean by "access a sharepoint application" exactly? What do you need from the application? If you only need to access List(s) use what Ashutosh gave in his answer otherwise please elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Add WebService reference(Name : SourceLists) to the project (Web service URL    https://……./sites/_vti_bin/lists.asmx)
2. SourceLists.Lists  sourceListService = new SourceLists.Lists();

System.Net.NetworkCredential  networkCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(“userid”, “pwd”);

sourceListService.Credentials = networkCredentials;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963346/authenticate-with-sharepoints-authenticate-asxm-web-service) a handy reference.