# Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i m using sharepoint webservice admin.asmx to create a site collection in my webapp
using following method

adminService.CreateSite(fullUrl, siteName, string.Empty, LCID, SITE_TEMPLATE, loginName, displayName, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);

adminService is object of this service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are giving the sharepoint administrator credential to the webservice before calling the adminService.CreateSite...

Comment: i have done that all right bro. if i tries to instantly troubleshoot , the reason it gives is:                              The exception that is thrown when an XML Web service method is called over SOAP and an exception occurs.
i am not able to understand this as it does not provide its solution

Comment: Download the client demo from http://www.sharepointmonitor.com/2007/01/sharepoint-web-service/  it might help u.

Comment: below is the function in which i m calling i m passing http://svrsaim:54321/ as sharepointUrl and some arbitrary name as sitename                                                      public void CreateSharepointSite(string sharepointURL, string siteName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating SharePoint SiteCollection");
            string fullUrl = sharepointURL + "/sites/" + siteName;
            adminService.CreateSite(fullUrl, siteName, string.Empty, LCID, SITE_TEMPLATE, loginName, displayName, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
            
        }

Comment: Are you pass sing network credentials see the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040664/how-can-i-authenticate-sharepoint-user-credentials/4042422#4042422